# Load RSA private key generated by openssl to MacOS SecKeyRef fails

Tags: ios, macos, security, openssl

I am working on a project that needs to read a RSA private key (DER format) into a MacOS's SecKeyRef object.

I generate the key by

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

I load the private.der to MacOS by using SecKeyCreateWithData:

```
unsigned char *keyBytes; // contains all the bytes from the file "private.der"
int keyBytesLen; // length of the data loaded
NSData keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:keyBytes length:keyBytesLen];
NSDictionary* options = @{(id)kSecAttrKeyType: (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, 
                          (id)kSecAttrKeyClass: (id)kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                          (id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @1024};
SecKeyRef privateKey = SecKeyCrecateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) keyData, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options, &error);

OSstatus status = SecKeyDecrypt(privateKey, .... some encrypted message);
// status returns -50 (errSecParam)
```

So I notice the privateKey is loaded successfully, but it fails to decrypt the encrypted message. I am 100% sure other parameters I have put into SecKeyDecrypt() function is correct because it works if I generate the privateKey by macOS's built-in function rather than loading from a DER-format file generated by openssl.

I also notice that when I dump the key (binary format), the first few bytes (version header) is different from the key generated by MacOS's built-in function and openssl. If the key is generated by MacOS (ex: SecKeyGeneratePair) and outputed by SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation, the first few bytes look like:

```
3082 025d 0201 0002 8181 ...
```

while the key generated by openssl looks like:

```
3082 025c 0201 0002 8181 ...
```

I know (based on PKCS#1) that these bytes represent the "version" of the private key but not sure how to interpret it.

Any help or similar working example to load key generated by openssl to MacOS's API will be appreciated